# Splitting string in java containing relational operators

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have a string which has relational operators:

```
"x<y , x=y , x<=y , x>y , x>=y"
```

How can I split this?

If I use `[<>=]` it'll split `x<=y` as (`x` and `=y`).

Is there any simple way to do it without writing our own function to split?

Comment: use `[<>=]+` (not the `+`) to match multiple chars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to split using any sequence of characters (and not only any character), then you should use:

```
[<>=]+
```

The `+` here means **1 or more**

Comment: what + here means? (we would give "<+" for 1..* < but this one?)

Comment: @Dineshkumar, you should be aware that the above pattern will also match things like `<<`, `>>`, `=<`, `=>`, and `==`.

Comment: More precisely, `[<>]=?|=`

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Recursive Descent Parser. Is easy to implement and easy to mantain. You might want to look [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/07/30/building-a-simple-recursive-descent-parser.aspx).

Comment: True but this is a scanning problem, not a parsing problem (yet). Not an answer.